# Hosting spring web service in embedded jetty

Tags: spring-mvc, embedded-jetty

Problem: Host a spring web service in embedded Jetty. 
This needs to work for both unit testing and prod environments. The application is packaged in a jar and the entry point starts other services apart from Jetty. Using WAR file/setwar/WebApplicationContext on WEB-INF is not an option since package is jar.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);
    DispatcherServlet springServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    springServlet.setContextConfigLocation("classpath:spring-servlet.xml");
    final ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new
            ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    contextHandler.setContextPath("/");
    contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(springServlet), "/*");
    jettyServer.setHandler(contextHandler);

    contextHandler.getInitParams().put("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml");
    ContextLoaderListener listener = new ContextLoaderListener();
    contextHandler.addEventListener(listener);

    jettyServer.start();
    jettyServer.join();
```

Comment: AFAIK, this won't give you JSP support which many uses of SpringMVC make use of.